# <BEA-050001> <WLContext.close() was called in a different thread than the one in which it was created.>

Tags: weblogic, wlst

Unable to activate the changes when I deploy multiple ears through WLST script. The error is as below and unable to activate the changes.

```
    WLSTException: Error occurred while performing activate : Error while Activating changes. : weblogic.application.ModuleException: Context path '/deployment' is already in use by the module: deployment application: my.ear
```

My script is:

```py
import os
import sys
import java

def connectAdmin() :

    print('connecting to the url:')

    try:
        connect(username, password, url)
        print('Successfully connected')
    except:
        print 'Unable to find admin server...'
        exit()

def deployApplication() :
       directory='D:/AMSP/VerCrossCorp/Srinivas/DOMAIN_HOME/amspv97-9709-wl12/servers/AdminServer/deployment' 
       for filename in os.listdir(directory):
                if filename.endswith(".war") or filename.endswith(".ear"):    

                    progress=deploy(filename,directory,targets='AdminServer')


if __name__== "main":

        print 'starting the script ....'
        username = 'weblogic'
        password = 'weblogic'
        url='t3://172.27.49.161:9709'
        connectAdmin()
        edit()
        startEdit()
        deployApplication()
        activate()
        disconnect()
```

Comment: Add the error raised during deployment and format your code please

Comment: Hi Emmanueal Collin, formatted the code and added the error stack. Please suggest me where I am going wrong.

Comment: You are trying to deploy an application which is already deployed. Undeploy it before running your script

Comment: There were no ears and wars deployed before. The console is empty. I am deploying in fresh console. Still facing the same error.

Comment: Check your context paths in all your applications, may be many applications are using the same

Comment: Yes, all our applications have almost same context path. Is that casue any issue. If i deploy through console, i havent faced any issues.

Comment: Each application must have a distinct context path.

Comment: No, we cannot change the application context paths. Will, you please suggest any other alternative.

Comment: a context path must be unique per server. You can create a managed server per application. 
You can also use a deployment plan to update the context path of each application without updating the application itself

Comment: Will you please guide me on how to write a deployment plan. I have never tried of writing the deployment plan.